# Interface doubts

Tags: interface

Are interfaces a layer between objects(different objects) and actions(different object types trying to perform same action)? and Interface checks what kind of object is it and how it can perform a particular action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about the term "interface" as used in a specific language (such as Java or Objective-C), or the generic meaning of the term?

If the latter, then an "interface" can be almost anything.  Pour oil on water -- the line between them is an "interface".  An interface is any point where two separate things meet and interact.

The term does not have a rigorous definition in computing, but refers to any place where two relatively distinct domains interact.

Comment: I am talking about interface in general as a concept in computing/programming.

Comment: Well, then, it's any place two domains interact.  It may be "well-defined" or "ad hoc".  There may be rigorous checking of parameters at the interface, or it may be unchecked.  It may follow a standardized pattern with naming conventions, standard return codes, etc, or each individual function may be defined in a different way.

Comment: So basically Interface is that layer with monitors whether two domains are interacting in an acceptable manner? When you say domains interacting, does that mean Objects interacting with Objects?

Comment: Basically, an "interface" is whatever you say it is.  Any two objects interacting with each other can be called an "interface".  The "UI" -- "User Interface" -- is an "interface".  The boundary between hardware and software is an "interface".  This forum is an "interface".

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that it's better to think of an interface as a promise. In Java there is the interface construct that allows for inheritance of an API, but doesn't specify behavior. In general though, an interface is comprised of the methods an object presents for interacting with the object.

In duck-typed languages, if an object presents a particular set of methods (the interface) specific to a particular class, then that object is like the specifying class.

Enforcement of interface is complicated, since you need to specify some set of criteria for behavior. An interesting example would the design-by-contract ideas in Eiffel.

Comment: So lets say we have two objets(employee and customer) trying to perform an action(subscribe). Here employees can subscribe directly and customers need to pay and then subscribe. We have an interface IPerson who checks what kind of person it is. Will Employee and Customer classes have their own subscribe methods?

Comment: That depends. You have three paths. 1) Employee and Customer are unrelated except that they share an interface. They will have their own methods. 2) One inherits from the other or 3) They inherit from a common base class. They may or may not have their own methods.

Comment: In case they have no inheritence relationship, They would have their own methods. So will IPerson have a subscribe method as well? what would it do? and how? What would the Subscribe method of Interface IPerson contain? as we already have individual subscribe methods for classes Employee and Customer

Comment: Now we're getting into language specifics. Assuming Java (or language with a similar interface concept) Employee and Customer each have their own subscribe method. IPerson, if it's a Java interface, only specifies signatures not implementations. If however IPerson is not a Java-like interface, but another class then the IPerson subscribe method will contain whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that implementing Interface concept may be different for different programming languages. I am trying to understand Interface in general. When you say "think of an interface as a promise" what type of promises would a class need to fulfill if it wants to implement a particular interface? Could you give an example to understand it better?

Comment: For Java take a look at the event handlers for AWT. An simple example would be the MouseAdapter http://goo.gl/HBasg which implements several interfaces for convenience when building event handlers for mouse events. A more interesting example is the StringIO class http://goo.gl/aMkr from Python which is a file-like object in that it supports file operations on a string. Since a StringIO object is file-like, it can be used where you would normally use a file. The file-like classes allow you do do things like use strings in place of files for testing and defaults.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5991/discussion-between-john-percival-hackworth-and-user793468)

Answer (score 0):

To understand interfaces in .net or Java, one must first recognize that inheritance combines two concepts:

1. Implementations of the derived type will include all fields (including private ones) of the base type, and can access any and all public or protected members of the base type as if it were its own.

   Objects of the derived type may be freely used in place of objects of the base type.

Allowing objects to use members of more than one base type as their own is complicated.  Some languages provide ways of doing so, but there can often be confusion as to which portion of which base object is being referred to, especially if one is inheriting from two classes which independently inherit from a third.  Consequently, many frameworks only allow objects to inherit from one base object.

On the other hand, allowing objects to be substitutable for more than one other type of object does not create these difficulties.  An object representing a database table may, for example, allow itself to be passed to a routine that wants a "thing that can enumerate contents, which are of type T (IEnumerable<T> in .net)", or a routine that wants a "thing that can have things of type T added to it" (ICollection<T> in .net), or a thing that wants a "thing that wants to know when it's no longer needed (IDisposable in .net)".  Note that there are some things that want notification when they're no longer needed that do not represent enumerable collections, and there are other things that represent enumerable collections that can be abandoned without notification.  Thus, neither type of object could inherit from the other, but if one uses an interface to represent "things which can enumerate their contents, which are of type T", or "things that want to know when they are no longer needed", then there's no problem having classes implement both interfaces.